# PHP- Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '$' in

Tags: php

[image: 1image]
[image: 2image]
[image: 3image]
[image: 4image]

`$email` has data; not empty but 
`!empty($email)` << false 
and `!empty('$email')` << true
But I have some problems

> Parse error syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '$' in

Comment: line 91 is ' if(!empty('$email') and !empty('$password'))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be using a version of PHP before 5.5. Per the manual:

> Prior to PHP 5.5, empty() only supports variables; anything else will result in a parse error.

-http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

The reason you are getting this is because anything single quotes is a string. Change it to:

```
if(!empty($email) and !empty($password))
```

and you should be good to go.

The issue and error message can be seen here, https://3v4l.org/EgfFb. I'd also recommend updating your PHP version because based on the error you are using <= 5.2.17.